# MDX - How to access only a given level of a hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, pentaho, multidimensional-cube

I have a hierarchy that follows the following pattern:

```
Date - Dimension name
DateID - Hierarchy name
Year - Level1 name
Month - Level2 name
Day - Level3 name
```

I want to get the number of hotel stays per month (level2), without it being expanded by year (level1)

Right now, I have the following MDX query, which kind of works but gives me 24 months (12 for each year) instead of what I want which is only 12 months (the total per month regardless of the year):

```
select [Measures].[Booking id] ON COLUMNS,
  [Date].[Month].MEMBERS ON ROWS
from [grupo1_hotel_booking]
```

Any ideas how I might be able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

For a user hierarchy like that there are attribute hierarchies in the cube.

So maybe something like [Month].[Month].MEMBERS

The attribute hierarchies may be hidden by the cube designer.

Comment: Wow! That magically works for me.